# How to make a .js file play from within my .iim file?

Tags: imacros

I am using this command within my macros script

```
"URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=your-javascript.js"
```

to call JavaScript file saved at same location as my macro file is stored
Location where both files are saved: `\\C:\Users\PPawar1\Documents\iMacros\Macros\Demo-Firefox\DemoTest`.

I tried this way :

```
URL GOTO=\\C:\Users\PPawar1\Documents\iMacros\Macros\Demo-Firefox\PriyaTest://run/?m=PageLode.js
```

However I am getting this error:

> Error loading page http://c/Users/PPawar1/Documents/iMacro ...
>   ageLode.js, line 29 (Error code: -933)

Do I need to make any changes in this command "URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=your-javascript.js" as per the path mentioned above to call .js file?

JavaScript file name is : pageload.js

```
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

 if(width==360 && height==640 || width==435 && height==773 || width==375 && height== 667 || width==411 && height==731 || width==320 && height==568 || width==414 && height== 736)
 {
 iimDisplay("Skipping 1W, 3M, 3Y, 5Y execution for this screen having width of : "+width+" and height of : "+height);
 }
    else if(width==1024 && height==1024 || width==768 && height==1024)
    {
    iimDisplay("Skipping 1M execution for this screen having width of : "+width+" and height of : "+height);
    }
```

Also can we execute the same JavaScript mentioned above with EVAL command?

Comment: You should read their iimPlay wiki page: http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay() and the forum post mentioned at the end of it: http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=21710&p=54684#p54684

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the following changes:

```
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=Demo-Firefox/DemoTest/PageLode.js
```

***Note:*** generally speaking, to run js-scripts from iim-macros is not a good idea enough.

---

'iMacros' cannot execute the JavaScript code you mentioned above, with the `EVAl` command

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I am able to call the .js file from .iim in Firefox browser; however I am unable to do the same in Chrome and IE browser.
But it’s giving error as “RuntimeError: Page loading timeout” for above line.
Why it is unable to call .js file save in Demo-Chrome/Priya_Chrome folder?
Also, I tried to run direct .js file as well and it was successfully executed in Firefox browser; however I was unable to call the same in Chrome and IE browser.
Is there any different setting I need to do for chrome and IE browser?
Even I was unable to view .js file saved in Demo-Chrome

Comment: The reason is that 'iMacros' for Chrome and IE browsers doesn't support js-scripts as you did it. However you can run some of them as pseudo-URLs, i.e. with the help of `URL GOTO=javascript:...` .

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
can you please elaborate it more? 
Do you meant that I need to make following changes?

URL GOTO=javascript://run/?m=Demo-Chrome/Priya_Chrome/PageLode.js

instead of calling it like this from .iim
'URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=Demo-Chrome/Priya_Chrome/PageLode.js

Comment: I guess that you have to read some info about the [`URL` command](http://wiki.imacros.net/URL#Using_Javascript) .

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
It was very useful.
I made the changes and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use URL Goto to call js file then your main macro is stopped.
To call js file in main macro, your main macro should be in js format, then in main macro you can call local js.
You can visit here for your answer: http://wirecellar.com/2FJZ